# How to read a large file from FTP location in server

Tags: java, ftp, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have to read large(say 20mb) pipe delimited file from a FTP location and store into DB. What would be the best way to do so.

Some approaches:
1. Copy file locally and then read it and save to DB.
2. Reading directly from stream and saving into DB.

Please suggest some efficient way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think option-1 will be better ,

In case of option 2 -What if there is some exception - while reading the file using stream or exception while writing the file in DB , how will you come to know exactly where it have failed ,

with option 1 you can store file temp directory , then write the file in DB and then delete or archive from the temp directory.

Archiving file on file system will be preferable  - it will be of use in the future references .

There are many examples around for both -

For file download from ftp you can follow - 
http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example

Answer (score 0):

When its a sql or csv file you can try it via ssh.

```
mysql -u root -p

set global net_buffer_length=1000000; --Set network buffer length to a large byte number

set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000; --Set maximum allowed packet size to a large byte number

SET foreign_key_checks = 0; --Disable foreign key checking to avoid delays,errors and unwanted behaviour

source file.sql --Import your sql dump file

SET foreign_key_checks = 1; --Remember to enable foreign key checks when procedure is complete!
```